# Why constant value change doesn't consider as error?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

Having to follow code  -

```
    const int WEEKDAYS = 7;
    const int *pWeekdays = &WEEKDAYS;
    *((int*) pWeekdays) = 9;
    cout << WEEKDAYS << endl;
```

it give output `7`  , that is - the line `*((int*) pWeekdays) = 9;` had no effect or thrown any errors .

Apparently it's like to do `7 = 9` so why no errors are being thrown ?

Comment: Undefined behaviour doesn't have to be checked or handled. If you were actually doing this in real code, C++ isn't going to make up for your stupidity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting away constness and thus accessing a const object mutably is simple **undefined behaviour**. Your program can do anything it wants, and no diagnostic is required.

Always remember that while it's true that a crashing program is buggy, a buggy program doesn't always crash. (Or as Socrates would have said, "not every cat is a fish".)

---

In C++ you should really never use C-style casts. If you had tried the more appropriate `static_cast<int*>(pWeekdays)`, you would have got the correct diagnostic.

Comment: *"Casting away constness is simple undefined behaviour."*. Not always, and not necessarily!

Comment: @Kerrek SB It's only UB if you then mutate the casted-to value actually.

Comment: @MarkB: Yes yes, I know - I've long since updated the answer :-) (Also note that we're not casting the value. We're casting a pointer to a variable.)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `WEEKDAYS` as a constant and you are updating `*pWeekdays` i.e. **value at address** stored in `pWeekdays` so **technically you are not updating the constant.**

The reference `WEEKDAYS` or `pWeekdays` are not updated which you defined as a `constant`